# Node JS + Express - move the entire project folder to a different directory on the same drive

Tags: node.js, express

I need to move the source code (folder) for my Express web application to a different directory (the same drive) on my Windows 7 OS.

I copied the entire folder to the destination directory. However, when I ran `npm start` off the new project directory on the command prompt window, it failed.

```
> node ./bin/www

module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node-fetch'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Work\Support Craig B\Equipment App\express-parse-equipment-app\routes\users.js:5:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! express-parse-equipment-app@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the express-parse-equipment-app@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\chena\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-18T12_41_04_928Z-debug.log
```

Is this error project specific or if not what is the best practise to move a Express project source folder?

Comment: run `npm install` and then `npm start`

Comment: I ran `npm install` and it returned `up to date in 2.724s`. Then I ran `npm start`, and it threw the same error.

Comment: are you sure you copied all the folders? can you post the source code to a github repo? @alextc

Comment: Thanks to all for your advice. For some unexpected reason `node-fetch` was not listed in package.json. I tried to install the module and it runs now.

Comment: Run `npm install node-fetch`

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm prune` then `npm install`.

If that still doesn't work, might be an npm cache issue. Try deleting the cache: `rm -rf ~/.npm` then running `npm install` again.